# How to parse the date string like '21Jul12'

Tags: java, date, dataformat

How to parse the date string like '21Jul12'. I have tried the following way:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time._

DateUtils.parseDate("21Jul12", Array("ddMMMyy"));
```

but it can't work due to the error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse the date: 21Jul21
    at org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.parseDateWithLeniency(DateUtils.java:359)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.parseDate(DateUtils.java:285)
    at .<init>(<console>:20)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Even I use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, i got a similiar exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "21Jul12"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at .<init>(<console>:13)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Are you parsing `2012 Jul 21`or `21Jul12` ?

Comment: The message in the exception indicates that the date that you're trying to parse is "2012 Jul 21", and not "21Jul12".

Comment: "21Jul12" means "2012-07-21". Is there a way to parse it directly?

Comment: how about using simpledateformat class from java API?? ..

Comment: that version of "commons.lang" use? There is a similar error detected with 2.4 and is fixed in 2.5

Comment: @ManuNavarro the version of `commons-lang` is 2.6

Comment: @chaitanya10 The same error for using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @爱国者 i tried using simple date format and i dint get any exception . i posted my answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works when I set the locale to Locale.en_US explicitly. Exception thrown because of the default locale setting is `Locale.CHINA`

Comment: Perfect, works too for me setting the Local in my SimpleDateFormat constructor : `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the above mentioned dates to parse

```
System.out.println("ddMMMyy >>>" + DateUtils.parseDate("21Jul12", new String[] { "ddMMMyy" }));

System.out.println("yyyy-MM-dd >>>" + DateUtils.parseDate("2012-07-21", new String[] { "yyyy-MM-dd" }));

System.out.println("yyyy MMM dd >>>" + DateUtils.parseDate("2012 Jul 21", new String[] { "yyyy MMM dd" }));
```

and the result on the console

```
ddMMMyy >>>Sat Jul 21 00:00:00 CEST 2012
yyyy-MM-dd >>>Sat Jul 21 00:00:00 CEST 2012
yyyy MMM dd >>>Sat Jul 21 00:00:00 CEST 2012
```

maybe you tried to parse "2012 Jul 21" with "ddMMMyy"

```
System.out.println("ddMMMyy >>>" + DateUtils.parseDate("2012 Jul 21", new String[] { "ddMMMyy" }));
```

gives your stack

```
java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse the date: 2012 Jul 21
at org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.parseDateWithLeniency(DateUtils.java:359)
at org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.parseDate(DateUtils.java:285)
at com.collibra.dgc.core.model.activity.impl.TestTree.testname(TestTree.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: +1 DateUtils.parseDate takes and array of formats ... I'm such and idiot... :P

Answer (score 0):

We use a process of elimination for our date parsing, basically, we use an array of commonly used date formats (for our application) and the one that doesn't throw an exception is the one we use.  Not the cleanest of solutions, but it works...

For example

```
parse("2012 Jul 21", "ddMMMyy", "yyyy MMM dd");
parse("21Jul12", "ddMMMyy", "yyyy MMM dd");


public Date parse(String value, String... formats) throws ParseException {
    Date date = null;

    for (String format : formats) {
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException exp) {
        }
    }

    if (date == null) {
        throw new ParseException(value + " is an unrecognized date format", 0);
    }

    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String date="21JUL12";
        try {
            System.out.println(new   SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy").parse(date));
        }
        catch(ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the above code gives me this output:

```
Sat Jul 21 00:00:00 BST 2012
```

Comment: are you still getting parse exception ??

Comment: can u post the exception you are getting when you try parsing with Simpledateformat.parse() method ..

Comment: @chaitanya10h i update my question. BTW, I also try your test case, but got the same exception

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroRless  it works when I set the **locale** to `Locale.en_US` explicitly. Exception thrown because of the default locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(                                          // Represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone using the `LocalDate` class.
    "21Jul12" ,                                           // A poor choice of format for date value as text. Instead use standard ISO 8601 formats.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMMuu" , Locale.US )  // Specify `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in translating.
)
```

No need for *Apache* utilities.

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

```
String input = "21Jul12" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMMuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2012-07-21

Two tips:

- **Use 4-digit years.**

  - Saving the space of two digits is not worth the ambiguity, confusion, and errors I have seen spawned both among programmers and users/readers. Pixels and toner are cheap enough nowadays that I suspect you can afford the two extra digits for century.
  - In any event, the *java.time* classes assume 21st century (`20xx`) if omitted.
- **Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats** for exchanging date-time values as text.

  - These formats are wisely designed to be unambiguous, easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans across various cultures.
  - The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).